# bench/BenchTimer.h (31) syntax error: 'volatile'

Tags: c++, eigen

Could you help me with this flabbergasting error in Eigen? "bench/BenchTimer.h (31) syntax error: 'volatile'"

The offending code: **bench/BenchTimer.h**

```
static void escape(void *p) {
  asm volatile("" : : "g"(p) : "memory");
}

static void clobber() {
  asm volatile("" : : : "memory");
}
```

My code: **tests.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <bench/BenchTimer.h>

    int main() {
            Eigen::BenchTimer t;
            t.reset(); t.start();

            //TestEigenSolveSpeed();

            t.stop();
            std::cout << t.value()  << std::endl;

            return 0;
    }
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

    set(LEVELING_NAME test-eigen)

    project(${LEVELING_NAME})

    add_executable(${LEVELING_NAME} tests.cpp )

    target_include_directories(${LEVELING_NAME} PUBLIC
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/eigen-master 
    )
```

**Folder structure:**

```
    /
    |
    -- CMakeLists.txt
    -- tests.cpp
    -- deps
       |
       -- eigen-master
```

Created solution with:
`cmake . -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -B build`

In Windows, in VS2017

with newest repository version: master version 3.3.3

Here is the three files plus the repository in a zip for ease of reproduction: https://www.dropbox.com/s/avpfbabo4l9ti5h/test-eigen-error-volatile.zip?dl=0

Comment: Assuming [this](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/bench/BenchTimer.h) is your source file, the error is at line [`asm volatile("" : : "g"(p) : "memory");`](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/bench/BenchTimer.h#L31).

Comment: You need to comment out those two inline asm statements to make MSVC happy.

Comment: Hi ggael, is this a known issue? Should I (or you) create an 'Issue' in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ggael mentioned, the solution is commenting the two offending code lines:

```
static void escape(void *p) {
  //asm volatile("" : : "g"(p) : "memory");
}

static void clobber() {
  //asm volatile("" : : : "memory");
}
```

This "volatile" does not seem supported/accepted by MSVS2017

It is however already fixed by ggael in the newest version of the repository :)